# Relative clause pronouns: was

Tags: relative-clause

Confused by the use of *was* in the relative clause of the following sentence:

> Zerfrisst die Rüstung des Ziels, was dessen Rüstungswert deutlich beeinträchtigt.
>
> Erodes the armor of the target, significantly reducing its armor-value

or in an awkward, but more literal translation:

> Erodes the armor of the target, whose armor-value becomes reduced.

I am assuming that the *dessen* here is a genitive-case article that corresponds to the modified noun *Ziels*. My question is: is the *was* here necessary? if so, why and how does it affect the meaning?

Answer (score 2):

The literal translation is:

> Erodes the armor of the target, which significantly reduces its armor value.

*Was* corresponds to *which*.

The literal translation of

> Erodes the armor of the target, whose armor value is significantly reduced.

is

> Zerfrisst die Rüstung des Ziels, dessen Rüstungswert deutlich beeinträchtigt wird.

The relative pronoun *was* in the German sentence refers to the eroding, not to the target as in your last translation. There is practically no difference in meaning but the original German sentence is a bit clearer about the reduction of the armor value being the effect of the eroding.

In the sentence above you can make it a bit clearer by adding *dadurch* (*by it*):

> Zerfrisst die Rüstung des Ziels, dessen Rüstungswert dadurch deutlich beeinträchtigt wird.

Another option would be to use *wodurch* as a relative pronoun:

> Zerfrisst die Rüstung des Ziels, wodurch dessen Rüstungswert deutlich beeinträchtigt wird.

which literally means:

> Erodes the armor of the target, by which its armor value is significantly reduced.

Comment: Actually the German sentence is not the original, but an [amateur translation](https://github.com/Spherikal/PoE2-EnhancedUserInterface/blob/master/.bin/PoE2-EnhancedUserInterface_2/localized/de_patch/text/game/abilities.stringtable) of an English sentence from the [Enhanced User Interface mod](https://www.nexusmods.com/pillarsofeternity2/mods/32) for the game *Pillars of Eternity 2*.

Comment: If *was* corresponds to which, what then does the *dessen* correspond to?

Comment: @SamuelSnow I have not downloaded any mods, so I am not sure what the source of the localization is. German is merely one of the pre-set language options in the settings. The above sentence is taken as it appears in the game. Are you perhaps suggesting that there are grammatical errors in the localization?

Comment: @PaoloMenuez No, it is grammatically correct, but "..., was" is colloquial and not standard written German. A professional writer might have chosen a less confusing way to phrase the sentence (because it takes a bit of thinking to understand it even for a native speaker). I'm not a UI professional and unfamiliar with this type of computer game, but I would have chosen something like: "Zerfrisst die Rüstung des Ziels **und beeinträchtigt dessen Rüstungswert**." or: "Zerfrist die Rüstung des Gegners und setzt dessen Rüstungswert um 50 Punkte herab."

Comment: *Was* as a relative pronoun is perfectly OK if it refers to the preceding clause which is the case here. It would be colloquial if it referred to *Ziel*.